# How to use SAML with JWT in an SSO React application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt, single-sign-on, saml

I have a React application that hits a Spring boot back end. I have been tasked with the final piece of integrating Single Sign On in the application using SAML. The application already was using json web tokens (JWT) for permissions management.

Is it possible to have SAML configured to only handle the authentication piece?

Ideally, the application would follow the following pattern:

```
User hits homepage -> Ping to backend sees that user is not logged in -> React app redirects user to SAML SSO login page -> Authentication -> Send user back to react application -> Back end issues JWT -> user goes on about their business
```

Trouble is, I  have a limited understanding of SAML, and only a slightly better understanding of JWT. I know Spring security will allow multiple auth providers, I am just not sure how to limit the SAML provider to authentication only.

Is this possible? How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "limit the SAML provider to authentication only". It's *your* choice as a Service Provider how authorization is implemented in your service.

Comment: I would like to use SAML to handle the login piece. The roles are configured within the application and are assigned there. Once the user has authenticated, the CN is provided to the app which gets the roles and creates JWT

Comment: There's no requirement that you use SAML token claims for authorization. You can just use the identity and assign authorizations (via roles or whatever's appropriate) within your app, no? Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62558112/exchange-saml-for-jwt-with-aad